# Check if a model is associated with another in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP for a while and ran into a problem where i need to check if the model is associated with some other model. Is there any built-in function for that?

**Example**

```
BLOG
 -- hasMany COMMENTS
 -- hasOne Profile

COMMENTS
 -- belongsTo BLOG
```

I am searching for some function like:

```
hasAssociation('blog', 'comments'); //should return true
hasAssociation('blog', 'whatever'); //should return false
hasAssociation('profile', 'blog'); //should return false
hasAssociation('blog', 'profile'); //should return true
```

If there is no such function how can i write my own? I am out of logic. Please suggest.

Comment: In what situation would you have a relationship that may or may not exist?

Comment: I implemented a notification system for my application using Long Polling. `NotificationsController` is handling all notification part. Its working great. But in order to display notification details i need to fetch details from database using ids returned by NotificationsController. These ids may represent different departments (there are 8) and i need check the associations before fetching the result. Its kind of hard to explain. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Surely then in your example the relationship always exists between Notification and Department. Whether there is data there is a whole other issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the function getAssociated

```
$this->yourModel->getAssociated();
```

And return the models associated

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getassociated-string-type-null

Comment: Not exactly what i need but it helped me to get the solution :)